# Why does the ifft2 image split in 4?

Tags: matlab

After doing a two-dimensional inverse Fourier transform in MATLAB, I got the 4-part split image of MRI. How can I solve this problem?

```
for i =1:8
raw_i = ifft2(kspace(:,:,i)); %kspace contains the 8-coil wise MRI data w.o undersampling , 160*160*8 matrix
imshow(abs(raw_i),[]);
```

[image: result]

Comment: Typically you would not take the absolute value of the result, but the real component. Depends on the application though. The meaning of the transform and whether to use `fftshift` as shown below depends on what is represented in `kspace`. Please [edit] your post with a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`fftshift`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fftshift.html) to rearrange the result; it shifts the zero frequency parts to the center of the image.

```
imshow(fftshift(abs(raw_i)),[]);
```